# How can I center an XML graphic within my XAML?

Tags: xaml, app.xaml

I am new to XAML and I am trying to figure out some of the ways you position things.  I have a graphic that started off as an Adobe Illustrator image which I then converted to code that renders fine as XAML.  However, I can't seem to get it to display centered within the display area.  Using horizontalalignment, I can center other things without issue, but for some reason, I can't seem to get this graphic to be centered.  I'm hoping that I just missed something.

```
<Window x:Class="play.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<StackPanel>
    <Viewbox xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Height="320">
        <Canvas x:Name="Layer_1" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Width="62" Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="#00AEEF">
            <!--Unknown tag: metadata-->
            <!--Unknown tag: sodipodi:namedview-->
            <Canvas x:Name="g3" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" x:Name="path5" Fill="White" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Path.Data>
                        <PathGeometry Figures="M16.733 8.245c-0.027-0.413-0.393-0.726-0.798-0.698c-0.413 0.027-0.726 0.385-0.698 0.798   c0.123 1.855-0.554 3.68-1.855 5.006c-1.199 1.225-2.783 1.899-4.46 1.899c0 0 0 0-0.001 0c-1.553 0-3.007-0.59-4.125-1.656   l1.177-1.177c0.28-0.279 0.081-0.758-0.314-0.758H2.38c-0.245 0-0.444 0.199-0.444 0.444v3.278c0 0.396 0.478 0.594 0.758 0.314   l1.041-1.041c1.401 1.35 3.231 2.096 5.185 2.096c0.001 0 0.001 0 0.002 0c2.082 0 4.047-0.835 5.53-2.349   C16.053 12.771 16.884 10.527 16.733 8.245z" FillRule="NonZero"/>
                    </Path.Data>
                </Path>
                <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" x:Name="path7" Fill="White" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                    <Path.Data>
                        <PathGeometry Figures="M2.075 10.503c0.413-0.031 0.723-0.391 0.692-0.804c-0.14-1.868 0.535-3.709 1.85-5.051   C5.819 3.424 7.403 2.75 9.079 2.75c1.594 0 3.085 0.618 4.213 1.736l-1.152 1.152c-0.28 0.28-0.082 0.759 0.314 0.759h3.278   c0.245 0 0.444-0.199 0.444-0.444V2.674c0-0.396-0.479-0.594-0.758-0.314l-1.066 1.065C12.941 2.024 11.074 1.25 9.079 1.25   c-2.083 0-4.048 0.834-5.533 2.348C1.93 5.248 1.101 7.513 1.272 9.811c0.029 0.395 0.358 0.694 0.747 0.694   C2.037 10.505 2.057 10.504 2.075 10.503z" FillRule="NonZero"/>
                    </Path.Data>
                </Path>
            </Canvas>
        </Canvas>
    </Viewbox>

</StackPanel>
```

Comment: What are you using to convert your path data? If it's [Mike Swanson's](http://www.mikeswanson.com/xamlexport/) (which is pretty damn handy) then make sure you're exporting it for the right thing. Before you do though, I'd combine/unite both those paths and export it as one path, and if it's done right then it shouldn't care about sizes and you shouldn't need a ViewBox since it's vector anyway. So what are you using to export the path data, and understand a lot of that stuff that exports with it is garbage you want to remove before putting into your application.

Comment: I opened the graphic in a application called Inkscape and then used save as >  Microsoft XAML.  I don't have Adobe Illustrator, but the app you linked looks cool.  I will save the info for the future.  The URL for the one I used is  https://inkscape.org/en/download/
I'm not sure about how to combine the two paths.  I will see if I can figure it out.
Thanks for the info.

Comment: Combining the paths took a few tries, but I got it working.  I removed the viewbox, but the graphic is still left aligned for some reason.  There isn't much code here, so it seems like it should be pretty easy to figure out, but I'm not having any luck.  I tried centering the inner canvas, I tried centering the outer canvas, but no joy.

Comment: Perhaps I should have explained the actual goal:  I will have the vector graphic centered over two text blocks that will be below the graphic.  The text changes based on language, so it changes a lot.  With that in mind, I am NOT set on the code example I provided.  The graphic should not react responsively outside of being centered over the text that will be below it. If there is a better way to do this, I'm happy to change my code.

Comment: Do you have Blend installed with Visual Studio? I just copy/pasted your thing in there. Selected both paths and did a quick Right Click->Combine->Unite to produce [this](http://pastebin.com/7rt4Xeta) but it's still not how I'd generally make that sort of thing. PS - If you don't use Illustrator, Blend is a handy tool to know when doing xaml design work, I'm not familiar enough with inkscape to say anything competently about it.

Comment: I am doing the visual work in Blend and C# in Visual Studio.  It looks like the issue might be my lack of understanding how 'canvas' works.  From what I just found in another Stack Overflow post, canvas just positions items in it in the upper left.  It looks like canvas is the wrong thing to use.  Here is a link to the other post I found.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/889112/perfect-center-on-wpf-canvas
Perhaps a stack panel will be the way to go.  One stack panel for the graphic and another for the text under it?

Comment: It's doing that because you have canvas.left and canvas.top declared. Realistically most of the time you'll never need canvas for simple stuff like that. If it were me, I'd just Border->StackPanel->Image & Text

Comment: Yes.  The canvas was the issue.  The developer that wrote the code I am working on doesn't seem to have had much more of an idea of which panels are for what than I do.  Oh well, I'm figuring it out!  I think that from here on out, I will probably just rewrite the display code for each of the pages rather than trying to debug them.  Thanks for all of the help!  No clue how to mark that ditching canvas was the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Canvas is only good for static placement of graphics. 
You should start using grids and stackpanels.

I have modified your xaml:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Viewbox xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Height="320">
        <Grid x:Name="Layer_1" Width="62" Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="#00AEEF">
            <!--Unknown tag: metadata-->
            <!--Unknown tag: sodipodi:namedview-->
            <Grid x:Name="g3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" x:Name="path5" Fill="White" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Path.Data>
                        <PathGeometry Figures="M16.733 8.245c-0.027-0.413-0.393-0.726-0.798-0.698c-0.413 0.027-0.726 0.385-0.698 0.798   c0.123 1.855-0.554 3.68-1.855 5.006c-1.199 1.225-2.783 1.899-4.46 1.899c0 0 0 0-0.001 0c-1.553 0-3.007-0.59-4.125-1.656   l1.177-1.177c0.28-0.279 0.081-0.758-0.314-0.758H2.38c-0.245 0-0.444 0.199-0.444 0.444v3.278c0 0.396 0.478 0.594 0.758 0.314   l1.041-1.041c1.401 1.35 3.231 2.096 5.185 2.096c0.001 0 0.001 0 0.002 0c2.082 0 4.047-0.835 5.53-2.349   C16.053 12.771 16.884 10.527 16.733 8.245z" FillRule="NonZero"/>
                    </Path.Data>
                </Path>
                <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" x:Name="path7" Fill="White" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                    <Path.Data>
                        <PathGeometry Figures="M2.075 10.503c0.413-0.031 0.723-0.391 0.692-0.804c-0.14-1.868 0.535-3.709 1.85-5.051   C5.819 3.424 7.403 2.75 9.079 2.75c1.594 0 3.085 0.618 4.213 1.736l-1.152 1.152c-0.28 0.28-0.082 0.759 0.314 0.759h3.278   c0.245 0 0.444-0.199 0.444-0.444V2.674c0-0.396-0.479-0.594-0.758-0.314l-1.066 1.065C12.941 2.024 11.074 1.25 9.079 1.25   c-2.083 0-4.048 0.834-5.533 2.348C1.93 5.248 1.101 7.513 1.272 9.811c0.029 0.395 0.358 0.694 0.747 0.694   C2.037 10.505 2.057 10.504 2.075 10.503z" FillRule="NonZero"/>
                    </Path.Data>
                </Path>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>

</StackPanel>
```

Comment: The main difference between this solution and what I ended up implementing was that I followed the suggestion of Mike Swanson (above) and copied the value of the second path's figures and pasted it inside that of the first one and then deleted the second one.  It was a great suggestion that I hadn't considered.  Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should use a gird (Grid.RowDefinitions and Grid.ColumnDefinitions) to center your canvas instead of the HorizontalAlignment property

best of luck !